# featureContext file in Behat

Tags: symfony, behat

I was playing a little with Behat and I have two questions:

**ONE:**
I have to finish with a few .features file and only one featureContext.php?, why just one?

I'm surprised because that make me think that we can finish with a huge featureContext.php file if we include all our code for different features and scenarios in just onf file,  isn't it?. Am I wrong?.

**TWO:**
Is possible to use PHPSpec with behat?, make sense?, is usual?, I did it with phpunit, but I'd like phpspec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ONE**: You can use as many context as you want.

My current behat.yml (for Behat 3.0):

```
default:
    formatters:
        pretty:
            verbose: true
            paths: false
            snippets: false

    suites:
        issue:
            contexts:
                - MyBundle\Behat\Context\FeatureContext
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
                - behatch:rest
            filters:
                tags: "@issue && ~@javascript && ~@wip"
            paths: 
                - src/MyBundle/Features
    extensions:
        Sanpi\Behatch\Extension: ~
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url:    'http://localhost/'
            goutte: ~
```

thus I have my FeatureContext, MinkContext (privided by MinkExtension) and behatch:rest (provided by BehatchExtension).

**TWO** It's pretty common to use PHPSpec and Behat in the same project.
Behat (high level) describes behaviour of application, checks business logic. 
PHPSpec (low level) describes classes